# Simple Python Code Invalid Syntax

Tags: python

I keep geting an invalid syntax error in the 
`forguessesTaken in range(1, 7):` line. Python keeps saying the `:` is invalid syntax. This is driving me crazy. Can anyone help?

```
# this is a guess the number game.
import random
secretnumber = random.randint(1,20)
print('I am thinking of a number between 1 and 20.')

# ask the player to guess 6 times.

forguessesTaken in range(1, 7):
    print('take a guess.')
    guess = int(input())

    if guess < secretnumber:
        print('your guess is too low.')
        elif guess > secretnumber:
            print('your guess is too high.')
            else:
                break # this condition is the corret guess!

            if guess == secret number:
                print('good job! You guessed my number in ' + str(guessestaken) + 'guesses!')
                else:
                    print('nope. the number i was thinking of was ' + str(secretnumber))
```

Comment: Try adding a space after `for`.

Comment: you must have an space between for and guessesTaken

Comment: Thanks Amir that solved it :)

Comment: Also remember to capitalize the T in taken in the print line.

Answer (score 1):

There is no keyword in python called `forguessesTaken`. Maybe you forget to put space between `for` and `guessesTaken`. Put a space between them:

```
for guessesTaken in range(1,7):
    // remaining code...
```

Answer (score 0):

Use this code instead:

```
for guessesTaken in range(1, 8):
    if guessesTaken == 8:
        print('Nope. The number I was thinking of was', secretnumber)
        break
    guess = int(input('Take a guess: '))

    if guess < secretnumber:
        print('Your guess is too low.')
    elif guess > secretnumber:
        print('Your guess is too high.')
    else:
        print('Good job! You guessed my number in', guessesTaken, 'guesses!')
        break
```